# Why is not advised to use Bottom Navigation with ViewPager?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, bottomnavigationview

> Avoid using lateral motion to transition between views.

It appears [here](https://material.io/guidelines/components/bottom-navigation.html#bottom-navigation-behavior) in the scrolling section.
What's the reason why the specs say that?

Comment: Please be more specific in your question. Provide the document link, point out which section it's mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

> Don’t.
>
> Avoid using lateral (left-and-right) motion to transition between views. Lateral motion is reserved for navigating related content, such as tabs.

Please be clear that there's no document recommending not to use `BottomNavigationView` with `ViewPager`, the doc only advices not use lateral motion animation to transition between views of `BottomNavigationView`, instead you should use other types of animation (for example: fade in/fade out animation) for this kind of transition.

Answer (score -1):

Avoid using lateral (left-and-right) motion to transition between views. Lateral motion is reserved for navigating related content, such as tabs.